# JQuery slideToggle for multicolumn list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I`ve got a big list with the width of li 33%, so there are 3 columns.

```
computers   monitors   hi-fi
sex-toys    pancakes   scissors
```

In each of them there is UL hidden, which on click slideToggle.

**JQuery**

```
$('.subCategory > .parentleaf:has(ul) > .categoryicon').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

The problem that dont slide as I want, they rebuld the list every time, like so

```
computers   monitors   hi-fi
[li]cars    sex-toys   pancakes
[li]dogs    scissors
```

I want to slide them this way:

```
computers   monitors   hi-fi
[li]cars    pancakes   scissors
[li]dogs
sex-toys
```

How can I achieve this??

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLmYx/)

[**jsFiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLmYx/2/) - in this case need the red bg color be for 3 columns

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle code we can help much more

Comment: is there any problem if you added a `div` element somewhere ?

Comment: I only try writing semantic right code, so any help with this list is good

Comment: It's semantic right don't worry I will post my answer

Comment: Thanks, one of the solutions, will consider it, would accept it if I could make the background of toggled item different for 3 columns.

Comment: why you don't add a class for each 1 or inline style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `clearer div` between every three `li`

```
<ul class="subCategory">
    <li class="parentleaf">
        <span class="categoryicon">click</span>
        <span class="categoryname">Cars</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Car 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Car 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Car 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Car 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parentleaf">
        <span class="categoryicon">click</span>
        <span class="categoryname">Phones</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Phone 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Phone 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Phone 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Phone 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li class="parentleaf">
        <span class="categoryicon">click</span>
        <span class="categoryname">Guns</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Gun 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gun 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Gun 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gun 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <li class="parentleaf">
        <span class="categoryicon">click</span>
        <span class="categoryname">Notebooks</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Notebook 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notebook 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Notebook 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notebook 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearer
{
    clear:both; 
}
```

**You can also get the index of the current clicked `li` and with some math add a clearer div on click and remove it when needed but there I think there is no need for this**

Comment: thanks, this is one of the solutions, but not what I wanted. 
I dont want blank space from sides, only LI names do not change the order after toggle. Your solution is good too, but in this case I would like to do the background of toggled ul different color but for all 3 columns.

Comment: You welcome, if I had more time I will update the other solutions :)

Comment: updated the jsFiddle 2 - would accept it if the red would be for 3 columns and in this case I would toggle only 1 ul so need to control active state